# Facebook hacker

Tags: facebook

My Facebook account was hacked. Searching through security and settings info, Facebook showed that someone was logged into my account from another state and showed some kind of id number. The number contained 8 sets of four digits/letters combos separated by colons. (Ex: 1234:5678:9876:5f44:0000:564e:222e:abcd) what does this number represent and how can it be used to find the hacker?

Comment: Please contact Facebook support

Answer (score 4):

It looks like the IPv6 address of the machine that connected. It is made up of eight groups of four hexadecimal digits.

You can search for the owner of the network and inform the ISP of that network. There are many but http://ip-lookup.net will search for info about IPv6 addresses.

**Update:** I ran a lookup on my own address and got better results with https://www.ultratools.com.